# How to execute java class in jar file from Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I am fresher in Jmeter I have created a two class as

```
*package test;
public class Urlmap {
    static String turl=null;
    public String display(){
        String url="/xyz";
        Test2 t=new Test2(url);
        turl=t.x;
        return "/xyz";

    }
}
package test;
public class Test2 {
static String x=null;
Test2(String x){
    this.x=x;
}   
}*
```

I have imported the jar then trying to execute  the class in BeanShell Sampler of Jmeter

```
import test.Urlmap;
Urlmap u =new Urlmap();
log.info("xxxxxxxxxxxx :----"+u.display());
log.info("turl :----"+u.turl);
```

it is giving me error as --**Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import test.Urlmap;  Urlmap u =new Urlmap();  log.info("xxxxxxxxxxxx :----"+u.di . . . '' : Cannot access field: turl, on object: test.Urlmap@16ec122a 
2017/07/28 06:44:56 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`import test.Urlmap;  Urlmap u =new Urlmap();  log.info("xxxxxxxxxxxx :----"+u.di . . . '' : Cannot access field: turl, on object: test.Urlmap@16ec122a**

**But it working fine in Eclipse.**
*Is Jmeter can access one class value at a time not nested class value .*

Answer (score 4):

Remember, **Beanshell != Java**. Moreover, it is not the best scripting option as Beanshell interpreter has known performance problems.

So I would strongly recommend switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)  and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as Groovy's Java compatibility is much higher and Groovy engine has much better performance due to being able to compile well-behaved scripts into bytecode and caching the compiled scripts to speed up consecutive executions. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

With Groovy you will be able to use your code "as is"

[image: JMeter Groovy Example]

However accessing static fields via instance reference isn't a Java good practice, so I would recommend amending your code to

```
import test.Urlmap;
Urlmap u =new Urlmap();
log.info("xxxxxxxxxxxx :----"+u.display());
log.info("turl :----"+Urlmap.turl);
```

Comment: Thank you I will  check with JSR223 Sampler once for performace testing..m

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your `turl` field has a scope of package protected: It is only visible in the package `test`, but not from JMeter's package.

Solution: Replace `static` with `public`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want turl to remain static, just add public so it can be access by Jmeter

```
 public static String turl = null;
```

Also static field should be called with class name , use:

```
 Urlmap.turl
```